# В чем польза yield?

Tags: c#

Пример на С#.

Возвращаем коллекцию с помощью `yield`.

```
public static class Foo
{
    public static IEnumerable Test()
    {
        var rand = new Random().Next(1, 3);
        if (rand == 1)
            yield return 1;


        if (rand == 2)
            yield return 2;

        yield return 3;
        yield return "foo";
        yield return true;
    }
}
```

Пример 2. Возвращаем коллекцию с помощью обычного листа.

```
public static class Foo1
{
    public static IEnumerable Test()
    {
        var list = new List<object>();
        var rand = new Random().Next(1, 3);
        if (rand == 1)
            list.Add(1);

        if (rand == 2)
            list.Add(2);

        list.Add(3);
        list.Add("foo");
        list.Add(true);

        return list;
    }
}
```

Результат равнозначен, вопрос - зачем тогда вообще нужен `yield`, если можно обойтись таким кодом? Или `yield` используется там, где код с `new List()` по каким-то причинам невозможен?

Comment: отличается не результат выполнения, а процесс выполнения

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410026/

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Ну, отличие на самом деле кардинальное.

Дело в том, что в первом случае у вас *ленивое*, а во втором — *энергичное* вычисление ответа. Это значит, что элементы выходной последовательности в энергичном случае вычисляются все и сразу, а в ленивом случае — только когда запрошены и только те, что запрошены.

Давайте посмотрим, где с практической стороны есть разница.

Для случая ленивого вычисления вся последовательность не присутствует полностью в памяти. Это значит, что при поэлементной обработке у нас не выделяется память, и сохраняется cache locality:

```
IEnumerable<int> GenerateHugeSequenceLazy()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        yield return 13 * i;
}

IEnumerable<int> GenerateHugeSequenceEager()
{
    var result = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        result.Add(13 * i);
    return result;
}
```

Вычисляем функцию на всей последовательности, сравниваем расход памяти:

```
var seqLazy = GenerateHugeSequenceLazy();
// вычисляем максимум вручную
var max = 0;
foreach (var v in seqLazy)
    if (v > max)
        max = v;

var memLazy = GC.GetTotalMemory(forceFullCollection: false);

var seqEager = GenerateHugeSequenceEager();
// вычисляем максимум вручную
max = 0;
foreach (var v in seqEager)
    if (v > max)
        max = v;

var memEager = GC.GetTotalMemory(forceFullCollection: false);

Console.WriteLine($"Memory footprint lazy: {memLazy}, eager: {memEager}");
```

Результат:

```
Memory footprint lazy: 29868, eager: 6323088
```

---

Затем, у нас довольно большие различия в *смысле* операций. Энергичные вычисления производятся в момент вызова функции, в то время как ленивые вычисления происходят в момент, когда вы пользуетесь результатом. А значит, для реального вычисления ленивой последовательности состояние аргументов будет взято на момент перечисления. Вот пример:

```
IEnumerable<int> DoubleEager(IEnumerable<int> seq)
{
    var result = new List<int>();
    foreach (var e in seq)
        result.Add(e * 2);
    return result;
}

IEnumerable<int> DoubleLazy(IEnumerable<int> seq)
{
    foreach (var e in seq)
        yield return e * 2;
}
```

Смотрим на отличия:

```
var seq = new List<int>() { 1 };
var eagerlyDoubled = DoubleEager(seq);
var lazilyDoubled = DoubleLazy(seq);

Console.WriteLine("Eager: " + string.Join(" ", eagerlyDoubled));
Console.WriteLine("Lazy : " + string.Join(" ", lazilyDoubled));
// выводит оба раза 2, покамест различий нет

seq.Add(2); // модифицируем *исходную* последовательность

Console.WriteLine("Eager: " + string.Join(" ", eagerlyDoubled)); // 2
Console.WriteLine("Lazy : " + string.Join(" ", lazilyDoubled));  // 2 4
```

Поскольку ленивое вычисление происходит при *перечислении*, мы видим, что при изменении последовательности ленивая версия подхватывает изменения.

---

Другой пример. Посмотрим, что будет, если мы не вычисляем всю последовательность. Вычислим одну и ту же последовательность энергично и лениво:

```
IEnumerable<int> Eager10()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Eager");
    int counter = 0;
    try
    {
        var result = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Adding: {i}");
            counter++;
            result.Add(i);
        }
        return result;
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Eagerly computed: {counter}");
    }
}

IEnumerable<int> Lazy10()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Lazy");
    int counter = 0;
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Adding: {i}");
            counter++;
            yield return i;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Lazily computed: {counter}");
    }
}
```

Берём только 2 элемента из результата:

```
foreach (var e in Eager10().Take(2))
    Console.WriteLine($"Obtained: {e}");

foreach (var e in Lazy10().Take(2))
    Console.WriteLine($"Obtained: {e}");

foreach (var e in Lazy10())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Obtained: {e}");
    if (e == 1)
        break;
}
```

Получаем такой вывод на консоль:

```
Eager
Adding: 0
Adding: 1
Adding: 2
Adding: 3
Adding: 4
Adding: 5
Adding: 6
Adding: 7
Adding: 8
Adding: 9
Eagerly computed: 10
Obtained: 0
Obtained: 1
Lazy
Adding: 0
Obtained: 0
Adding: 1
Obtained: 1
Lazily computed: 2
Lazy
Adding: 0
Obtained: 0
Adding: 1
Obtained: 1
Lazily computed: 2
```

Видите разницу? Ленивый вариант прогнал цикл всего два раза, и не вычислял «хвост» последовательности.

---

Ещё одна разница между случаями — когда сообщаются ошибки. В случае энергичного вычисления они сообщаются сразу. В случае ленивого — лишь при перечислении результата. Пример:

```
IEnumerable<int> CheckEagerly(int value)
{
    if (value == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("value cannot be 0");
    return new List<int> { value };
}

IEnumerable<int> CheckLazily(int value)
{
    if (value == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("value cannot be 0");
    yield return value;
}
```

Применяем try/catch:

```
Console.WriteLine("Eager:");
IEnumerable<int> seqEager = null;
try
{
    seqEager = CheckEagerly(0);
}
catch (ArgumentException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception caught");
}

if (seqEager != null)
    foreach (var e in seqEager)
        Console.WriteLine(e);

Console.WriteLine("Lazy:");
IEnumerable<int> seqLazy = null;
try
{
    seqLazy = CheckLazily(0);
}
catch (ArgumentException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception caught");
}

if (seqLazy != null)
    foreach (var e in seqLazy)
        Console.WriteLine(e);
```

Получаем результат:

```
Eager:
Exception caught
Lazy:

Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: value cannot be 0
   at Program.<CheckLazily>d__3.MoveNext() in ...\Program.cs:line 59
   at Program.Run() in ...\Program.cs:line 45
   at Program.Main(String[] args) in ...\Program.cs:line 13
```

Для того, чтобы получить «лучшее из обоих миров», то есть, ленивое вычисление, но энергичную проверку аргументов, проще всего разделить функцию на две: энергичную проверку и ленивое вычисление без проверки. Для современных версий C# удобно использовать вложенные функции:

```
IEnumerable<int> CheckEagerlyEnumerateLazily(int value)
{
    if (value == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("value cannot be 0");
    return Impl();

    IEnumerable<int> Impl()
    {
        yield return value;
    }
}
```

Проверяем:

```
Console.WriteLine("Recommended way:");
IEnumerable<int> seqLazy = null;
try
{
    seqLazy = CheckEagerlyEnumerateLazily(0);
}
catch (ArgumentException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception caught");
}

if (seqLazy != null)
    foreach (var e in seqLazy)
        Console.WriteLine(e);
```

и получаем

```
Recommended way:
Exception caught
```

---

Ещё один случай различия — зависимость от внешних данных *в процессе вычисления*. Следующий код пытается влиять на вычисления, изменяя глобальное состояние. (Это не очень хороший код, не делайте так в реальных программах!)

```
bool evilMutableAllowCompute;

IEnumerable<int> EagerGet5WithExternalDependency()
{
    List<int> result = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (evilMutableAllowCompute)
            result.Add(i);
    }
    return result;
}

IEnumerable<int> LazyGet5WithExternalDependency()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (evilMutableAllowCompute)
            yield return i;
    }
}
```

Используем:

```
Console.WriteLine("Eager:");
evilMutableAllowCompute = true;
foreach (var e in EagerGet5WithExternalDependency())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Obtained: {e}");
    if (e > 0)
        evilMutableAllowCompute = false;
}

Console.WriteLine("Lazy:");
evilMutableAllowCompute = true;
foreach (var e in LazyGet5WithExternalDependency())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Obtained: {e}");
    if (e > 0)
        evilMutableAllowCompute = false;
}
```

Результат:

```
Eager:
Obtained: 0
Obtained: 1
Obtained: 2
Obtained: 3
Obtained: 4
Lazy:
Obtained: 0
Obtained: 1
```

Мы видим, что изменение глобальных данных даже после формальной отработки ленивой функции может влиять на вычисления.

(Это ещё один аргумент в пользу того, что функциональное программирование и мутабельное состояние плохо сочетаются.)

Comment: а разве первый `Join` не должен был _материализовать_ ленивость и остальные изменения не должны применяться?

Comment: вот про этот `string.Join`

Comment: А, все, попробовал, действильно :) итератор ж никуда не девается

Comment: @Grundy: Ну да, `string.Join` — это то место, где ленивая последовательность вычисляется. Но она не материализуется (то есть, не превращается в `List<>` или что-то подобное) и не кешируется.

Comment: Ну вот я почему-то думал, что после такого вызова, типа `ToList()` сам результат который возвращает функция тоже как бы фиксируется, но фиксируется только результат `ToList()` :)

Comment: вам бы книжки писать =) т.е. я правильно понимаю, что если нужно просто перечисление текущего состояния, то, чтобы не делать лишнюю работу, лучше его получать через `yield`, но если нужно фиксированное состояние, то сохранять копию в `List` или другую коллекцию?

Comment: @rdorn: Ну, мне кажется, это сложный вопрос, относится скорее к области проектирования API. Разные варианты функции имеют различное поведение, так что нужно подумать, что из этого реально нужно пользователю (и задокументировать это). С другой стороны, я часто использую lazy-коллекции внутри классов, а наружу выдаю материализованные результаты, если нужно (это позволяет гибко выбирать, когда материализовать последовательность, на уровне кода).

Answer (score 27):

Да, в данном случае результат одинаковый, но "стоимость" его получения разная. Не используя `yield` вы создаёте дополнительный объект `List`, который сначала наполняете объектами, дополнительно расходуя при этом ресурсы. С `yield` же объекты возвращаются "напрямую".

В первом случае, если в `foreach (object obj in Foo.Test())`, например, я решу, что мне нужны всего два элемента, и сделаю `break`, то на этом всё и закончится. Во втором случае, если мне нужно всего два элемента из итератора, мне придётся подождать пока внутри `Foo1.Test()` внутренний список заполнится всеми элементами, из которых уже потом я возьму только два.

Также с `yield` я могу возвращать элементы бесконечно или почти бесконечно. Вот, например, итератор, который возвращает последовательность треугольных чисел:

```
IEnumerable<long> Triangle()
{
    long t = 0;
    long next = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        t += ++next;
        yield return t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, но только у yield тоже есть своя стоимость -- сохраняются объекты, которые размещены в этой функции на стеке. И делается это неявно.

Answer (score 8):

В книге Джона Скита по C# очень хорошо раскрыт принцип работы оператора yield.

При наличии оператора `yield return` внутри метода компилятор строит на основе данного метода конечный автомат. Для реализации итератора конечный автомат обладает следующими свойствами:

- Он имеет некое начальное состояние
- При вызове `MoveNext()` выполняется код из метода `GetEnumerator()` по тех по, пока не будет достигнут оператор `yield return;`
- Когда используется свойство `Current`, он возвращает последнее
  выданное значение.
- Он должен знать, когда выдача значений завершена, чтобы метод
  `MoveNext()` мог возвратить `false`;

Если кратко, то значение элемента вычисляет в тот момент, когда происходит обращение к нему.