# Linq c#, особенности работы с IEnumerable<T>-ами

Tags: c#, linq

Простите, боюсь, не получится четко сформулировать вопрос и показать пример кода.

**Ситуация:**

Когда-то у меня было такое, что метод возвращал `IEnumerable<T>`, при этом, в какой-то момент при переборе элементов с помощью `foreach` оказывалось, что элементов там уже не было (как бы `IEnumerable<T>` пустой). И это при том, что изначально метод возвращал не пустой список.

```
//Допустим, метод GetElements() возвращает не пустой IEnumerable<Element>
var elements = SomeStaticClass.GetElements();

//затем не помню что происходит

//в итоге
foreach (var element in elements)
{
    //сюда не разу не зашли
}
```

То есть в каких-то случаях `IEnumerable<T>` оказывался просто перечислителем, уже без данных.

Однако если вначале сделать `GetElements().ToArray()`, то такой проблемы уже не наблюдалось.

```
//Допустим, метод GetElements() возвращает не пустой IEnumerable<Element>
var elements = SomeStaticClass.GetElements().ToArray(); //!!!!!

//затем не помню что происходит

//в итоге
foreach (var element in elements)
{
    //сюда зашли много раз
}
```

**Вопрос:**

В каких случаях так происходит? Это полезно знать, чтобы не плодить каждый раз `ToArray()`, даже когда не надо.

Comment: Такое происходит, когда между получением коллекции и итерированием, коллекция меняется где то в другом участке кода.

Comment: @tym32167, Спасибо, если все так просто, то очень хорошо. Думаю, что понял. То есть, IEnumerable представляат коллекцию, которая находится где-то за кулисами, которая может поменяться. А может ли быть такое, что сама коллекция, которую представляет IEnumerable уже затерта GarbageCollector-ом, а перечислитель и IEnumerable еще остался?

Comment: @AndreyK., не может. Но могут быть варианты, когда последовательность может быть "повторно неперебираемой", либо перебор последовательности тяжел (запрос к БД или к XML), тогда ее нужно сразу материализовать и уже перебирать столько раз, сколько нужно.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/505018/10105

Comment: @Андрей, спасибо! А в каком случае последовательность "повторно не перебираемая"? Только в том случае, если например, после единичной выдачи элемента он затирается? Или, например если после выдачи элемента была поставлена какая-нибудь галочка, что элемент был уже выдан? Или есть еще какие-нибудь хитрые случаи когда последовательность "повторно неперебираема"? Хотя, пока писал этот коммент, вижу, что VladD связанный вопрос прислал. Надо изучить, может быть там написано.

Comment: @AndreyK., ну это могут быть какие-то очереди от внешних устройств, например, у вас есть некий датчик температуры и он кладет каждую минуту в очередь показания, вы приходите через час и забираете всё что в очереди накопилось, естественно повторно эти данные не получить, поэтому их нужно материализовать и сохранить локально (в БД или хотя бы в коллекции в ОЗУ). Ну и какие-то реализации когда вы самостоятельно ограничиваете повторный перебор, например, имитация урны с шарами в лотерее, когда шары в случайном порядке извлекаются и потом их там уже нет.

Comment: @AndreyK. чтобы разобраться в Linq, мне когда то давно помогла вот эта книжка http://www.apress.com/us/book/9781430226536

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть два способа выполнения запроса LINQ: отложенное и немедленное выполнение.
При отложенном выполнении LINQ-выражение не выполняется, пока не будет произведена итерация или перебор по выборке.
Если точнее когда linq запрос возвращает IEnumerable ,эти запросы называется "отложенное". отложенный запрос, который в конечном итоге возвращает
IEnumerable, может перечисляться снова и снова, получая последние данные из
источника. В этом случае не нужно ни вызывать, ни объявлять
запрос заново.То есть выполнение запроса после его создания откладывается. Само получение результатов производится при переборе в цикле foreach.
Методы ToList,ToArray,ToXXX и которые возвращают одно атомарное значение или один элемент называется "немедленным".
Эти методы немедленно выполняется

```
    //Example
    List<string> people =new List<string> { "Larson", "Jonny", "Fredy", "Michael","Lanny" };

    //это отложенный запрос.до foreach мы можем изменить эти данные
    //на данный момент у нас ест 2 значение в result-e
    IEnumerable<string> result = people.Where(x => x.StartsWith("L"));



    // удалил один значений из листа.
    //это влияет и на наш result!!!!
    people.Remove("Lanny");

    //на данный момент у нас ест 1 значение в result-e
    foreach (string s in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, полезно, вроде проясняется. Если можно, задам тот же вопрос, что и другому участнику: А может ли быть такое, что сама коллекция, которую представляет IEnumerable уже затерта GarbageCollector-ом, а перечислитель и IEnumerable еще остался?

Comment: А, хотя только что получил ответ, что "не может"

Comment: компилятор учитывает все это сценарий с сборщиком мусора.по этому сбор мусора не производится.

Comment: @Suleymani компилятор тут не при чем. Коллекция не будет затерта потому что будет существовать живая ссылка на неё.

Comment: Ответ в общем норм, только есть небольшая неточность ```когда linq запрос возвращает IEnumerable ,эти запросы называется "отложенное"``` - это определяется linq провайдером, да и вернуться может не просто IEnumerable, а IQueryable. Хотя это, наверное, уже сложности.

Comment: @tym32167 интерфейс IQueryable тоже реализует IEnumerable.человек который задавал этот вопрос пока может обойтись и этими знаниями.

Comment: @Suleymani да я с этим и не спорил, я просто упомянул интерфейс IQueryable и что есть различия при работе с IQueryable и IEnumerable, так как для будущих читателей это может пригодится при работе с Linq.

Comment: @tym32167, поясните пожалуйста, что обозначает "определяется linq провайдером"? Наверное, то что за IEnumerable может стоять, например, Array или какая-нимудь гибкая меняющаяся штука, там yield-ы, например...

Comment: @AndreyK. Linq- это просто способ взаимодействия с чем то. Провайдер - это код, который позволяет обрабатывать Linq запросы к какому-либо источнику данных. Например, Linq to Objects, Linq to XML, Linq to SQL, Linq to Twitter, Linq to Active Directory.... Таким образом, что именно произойдет, когда вы запрашивете данные откуда-либо, зависит от реализации провайдера. В данном ответе используется Linq to Objects, так как запрашиваемые данные уже лежат в памяти