# В каких случаях необходимо или удобнее использовать оператор yeild?

Tags: c#

собственно вопрос - когда в рамках разумности - нельзя обойтись без этого оператора

Comment: это, по сути, снтаксический сахар, потому без него можно обойтись всегда, но с ним код короче и понятней

Comment: когда нужно проводить итерации, но можно обойтись и без него

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью yield можно получить результат без вычислений других результатов... Допустим есть некая коллекция которую нужно сгенерировать по некоторому хитрому алгоритму....
Так вот, с помощью yield ты можешь получить результат не генерируя всю коллекцию сразу. А сгенерировать только нужный элемент когда к нему обратишся.

Это неплохо сэкономит ресурсы если коллекция особенно велика или же если получение каждого обьекта долгое (например привязано к обращению к серверу, что создает значительную задержку).

Примеры можно посмотреть здесь:
[В чем польза yield?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/505018/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%B0-yield)

Comment: ну вы просто описали что этот `yield` делает, но вы не ответили на вопрос - `когда в рамках разумности - нельзя обойтись без этого оператора` ?

Comment: а вот это что?: ```Это неплохо сэкономит ресурсы если коллекция особенно велика или же если получение каждого обьекта долгое (например привязано к обращению к серверу, что создает значительную задержку). ```

Comment: Это можно решить и без yield, достаточно накидать свой итератор ( энумератор)

Comment: это же можно сказать и о пользе ```do while``` и ```foreach``` и ```for```, когда есть ```goto``` (да, в шарпе он тоже есть) но ты, почему-то, используешь циклы :) Вопрос был "в каких случаях необходимо и удобнее" и я ответил на этот вопрос :)

Comment: Ну это все понятно, я ведь не спорю (см мой коммент выше), вы просто не указали ничего этого в ответе. То есть на вопрос `когда без yield нельзя обойтись`, вы просто описываете что этот yield собой представляет, то есть имхо ответ не сходится с вопросом

Comment: окей, а когда без циклов невозможно обойтись если есть goto ? :) ВСЕГДА можно обойтись костылями. :) Но лучше писать без оных. Как по мне, то на вопрос я ответил.

Comment: Вы мне пишете то, с чем я и так согласен, просто я считаю, что это должно быть не в комментариях, а в ответе. Ну ок, не хотите добавлять это в ответ - как хотите, ваше право.