# Зачем в linq нужна ленивость?

Tags: c#, linq

Если говорить о linq to sql, это можно понять. На основе выражения формируется sql запрос и отправляется, когда будет полностью сформирован.

Но если отбросить linq to sql и говорить только о linq to objects, есть ли практическая ценность в ленивости? Почему бы не выполнять все методы сразу?

Comment: Для чего ленивость в `SQL`? Наверно оптимизация, да? Ну так почему простые запросы должны быть без нее?

Answer (score 11):

Ленивость нужна для оптимизации, чтобы не материализировать цепочку в процессе вычисления.

Посмотрите на пример.

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 10_000_000)
          .Where(n => n % 149 == 7)
          .Where(n => n % 271 == 9)
          .First()
```

Если вычисление было бы не ленивым, то сначала в памяти создался бы список размером 10 миллионов элементов, затем создался бы другой размером 67115 элементов, затем третий размером 247 элементов, и затем из него взялся первый элемент.

В случае ленивого вычисления, у вас не будет в памяти вовсе никаких списков! Цепочка LINQ сначала возьмёт единицу, она не пройдёт через первый фильтр и будет отброшена. Затем возьмёт двойку, она тоже не пройдёт первый фильтр и будет отброшена. и так далее будет продолжаться до числа 7, которое пройдёт первый фильтр, но не пройдёт второй. и тоже будет отброшено. И так далее до тех пор, пока не будет вычислен результат, дальнейшие числа обрабатываться вовсе не будут.

---

Заметьте, что вы легко можете из ленивого вычисления сделать энергичное:

```
var l1 = Enumerable.Range(1, 10_000_000).ToList();
var l2 = l1.Where(n => n % 149 == 7).ToList();
var l3 = l2.Where(n => n % 271 == 9).ToList();
var result = l3.First();
```

Из энергичного же вычисления сделать ленивое куда сложнее.

---

Возникает закономерный вопрос: хорошо, а если у нас нету в LINQ-запросе ни `First`, ни `Take`, ни `Skip`, и все данные реально нужно обрабатывать — в этом случае выгоды от ленивых вычислений нету?

Оказывается, выгоды есть и в этом случае. Например, энергично вычисленная последовательность занимает много памяти, и её может просто не хватить. (Да она может вообще быть бесконечной, как [в ответе @tym32167](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1218726/10105)!)

Выделение большого количества памяти и запись туда данных — гораздо более медленная операция, чем ленивая конвейерная обработка последовательности элемент за элементом, ведь при этом нужно выделять страницы физической памяти, и раз объём данных большой, то они не влезут в быстрый кэш процессора, и придётся работать с намного более медленной памятью.

При ленивой же обработке списка у вас в памяти [обычно] в каждый момент времени лишь данные, относящиеся к одному элементу последовательности, а это [обычно] довольно мало.

(Простое сравнение расхода памяти есть, например, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/505073/10105).)

Comment: _Из энергичного же вычисления сделать ленивое куда сложнее._ - а это возможно вообще?

Comment: @Grundy: Для вычислений одного значения поможет `Lazy<T>`, а вот для ленивых списков нужно руками переделывать код на сопрограммы, без этого вроде никак.

Comment: Ну вот да, про списки я имел ввиду, без переписи не получится ж

Comment: @Grundy: Редактирование кода — это и есть «куда сложнее», тут не выйдет локально ограничиться дописыванием явной материализации.

Answer (score 6):

В дополнение к предыдущему ответу, с ленивостью можно удобно перебирать бесконечные последовательности, например вроде бы бесконечный цикл

```
IEnumerable<int> GetFibonacci(){
    int prev = 0; 
    int curr = 1;
    
    yield return prev;
    yield return curr;
    
    while(true) 
    {
        int next = prev + curr;
        yield return next;
        (prev, curr) = (curr, next);        
    }
}
```

Но при этом у нас нет никаких проблем с перебором первых нескольких записей

```
foreach(var f in GetFibonacci().Take(10))
    Console.WriteLine(f);
```

Вывод

```
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
```

Comment: Только хотел дополнить про трюки с бесконечными последовательностями :)

Comment: @VladD дополни дополни. Лучше 1 полный ответ, чем 2 полуответа :)

Comment: Не-не, я всё равно лучше примера не придумаю. Мне ещё очень нравится вот какой пример: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5396731/276994 (там бесконечная рекурсия)

Comment: @VladD неплохо неплохо, но такие фокусы могут и голову сломать автору, с этим надо поаккуратней )